# How do I output updating values for my scoreboard

Tags: java, javafx

My program tracks balls properly but when I switch to the scoreboard pane it doesn't output the updated ball count. How would I get it to update the ball count when I switch back to the scoreboard scene from the controller scene. I also know there are multiple parts of the code still missing, I'm just focusing on getting an updated variable to show first and then going from there.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;

public class Scoreboard extends Application {
    private IntegerProperty Ball = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    //int Ball = 0;
    int Strike = 0;
    int Out = 0;
    int[] InningScore = new int[18];
    int HomeScore = 0;
    int AwayScore = 0;
    int Inning = 0;
    Scene Controlls, Score;

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //Ball add
        Button AddBall = new Button("Add Ball");
        AddBall.setOnAction(value - > {
            AddBall();
        });
        AddBall.setLayoutX(10);
        AddBall.setLayoutY(20);


        //Ball Reset
        Button ResetBall = new Button("Reset Balls");
        ResetBall.setOnAction(value - > {
            ResetBall();
        });
        ResetBall.setLayoutX(10);
        ResetBall.setLayoutY(50);

        //Strike Add
        Button AddStrike = new Button("Add Strike");
        AddStrike.setOnAction(value - > {
            AddStrike();
        });

        AddStrike.setLayoutX(110);
        AddStrike.setLayoutY(20);


        //Strike Reset
        Button ResetStrike = new Button("Reset Strikes");
        ResetStrike.setOnAction(value - > {
            ResetStrike();
        });
        ResetStrike.setLayoutX(110);
        ResetStrike.setLayoutY(50);

        //Out Add
        Button AddOut = new Button("Add Out");
        AddOut.setOnAction(value - > {
            AddOut();
        });
        AddOut.setLayoutX(210);
        AddOut.setLayoutY(20);

        //Out Reset
        Button ResetOut = new Button("Reset Outs");
        ResetOut.setOnAction(value - > {
            ResetOut();
        });
        ResetOut.setLayoutX(210);
        ResetOut.setLayoutY(50);

        //Score Up
        Button ScoreUp = new Button("Score Up");
        ScoreUp.setOnAction(value - > {
            ScoreUp();
        });
        ScoreUp.setLayoutX(310);
        ScoreUp.setLayoutY(20);

        //Score Down
        Button ScoreDown = new Button("Score Down");
        ScoreDown.setOnAction(value - > {
            ScoreDown();
        });
        ScoreDown.setLayoutX(310);
        ScoreDown.setLayoutY(50);
        //Switch View
        Button ShowScoreboard = new Button("Show ScoreBoard");
        ShowScoreboard.setOnAction(e - > primaryStage.setScene(Score));

        ShowScoreboard.setLayoutX(410);
        ShowScoreboard.setLayoutY(20);

        Button ShowController = new Button("Show Controller");
        ShowController.setOnAction(e - > primaryStage.setScene(Controlls));


        ShowController.setLayoutX(410);
        ShowController.setLayoutY(40);

        //Reset Scoreboard
        Button ResetScoreboard = new Button("Reset Scoreboard");
        ResetScoreboard.setOnAction(value - > {
            ResetScoreboard();
        });
        ResetScoreboard.setLayoutX(410);
        ResetScoreboard.setLayoutY(50);



        //Balls Label
        Label BallsLabel = new Label();
        BallsLabel.setFont(new Font(30));
        BallsLabel.setText("Balls");
        BallsLabel.setLayoutX(30);
        BallsLabel.setLayoutY(20);
        //Show Balls
        Label ShowBalls = new Label();
        ShowBalls.setFont(new Font(30));
        ShowBalls.textProperty().bind(new SimpleIntegerProperty(Ball.get()).asString());
        ShowBalls.setLayoutX(50);
        ShowBalls.setLayoutY(60);

        //Strikes Label
        Label StrikesLabel = new Label();
        StrikesLabel.setFont(new Font(30));
        StrikesLabel.setText("Strikes");
        StrikesLabel.setLayoutX(120);
        StrikesLabel.setLayoutY(20);
        //Show Strikes
        Label Strikes = new Label();
        Strikes.setFont(new Font(30));
        Strikes.setText("" + Strike);
        Strikes.setLayoutX(150);
        Strikes.setLayoutY(60);

        //Outs Label
        Label OutsLabel = new Label();
        OutsLabel.setFont(new Font(30));
        OutsLabel.setText("Outs");
        OutsLabel.setLayoutX(230);
        OutsLabel.setLayoutY(20);
        //Show Outs
        Label Outs = new Label();
        Outs.setFont(new Font(30));
        Outs.setText("" + Out);
        Outs.setLayoutX(250);
        Outs.setLayoutY(60);

        //Show Inning Label
        Label Inning = new Label();
        Inning.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning.setText("Inning");
        Inning.setLayoutX(10);
        Inning.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Home Label
        Label Home = new Label();
        Home.setFont(new Font(30));
        Home.setText("Home");
        Home.setLayoutX(10);
        Home.setLayoutY(240);

        //Show Away Label
        Label Away = new Label();
        Away.setFont(new Font(30));
        Away.setText("Away");
        Away.setLayoutX(10);
        Away.setLayoutY(190);

        //Show Inning 1 Label
        Label Inning1 = new Label();
        Inning1.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning1.setText("1");
        Inning1.setLayoutX(120);
        Inning1.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 2 Label
        Label Inning2 = new Label();
        Inning2.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning2.setText("2");
        Inning2.setLayoutX(170);
        Inning2.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 3 Label
        Label Inning3 = new Label();
        Inning3.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning3.setText("3");
        Inning3.setLayoutX(220);
        Inning3.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 4 Label
        Label Inning4 = new Label();
        Inning4.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning4.setText("4");
        Inning4.setLayoutX(270);
        Inning4.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 5 Label
        Label Inning5 = new Label();
        Inning5.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning5.setText("5");
        Inning5.setLayoutX(320);
        Inning5.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 6 Label
        Label Inning6 = new Label();
        Inning6.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning6.setText("6");
        Inning6.setLayoutX(370);
        Inning6.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 7 Label
        Label Inning7 = new Label();
        Inning7.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning7.setText("7");
        Inning7.setLayoutX(420);
        Inning7.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 8 Label
        Label Inning8 = new Label();
        Inning8.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning8.setText("8");
        Inning8.setLayoutX(470);
        Inning8.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Inning 9 Label
        Label Inning9 = new Label();
        Inning9.setFont(new Font(30));
        Inning9.setText("9");
        Inning9.setLayoutX(520);
        Inning9.setLayoutY(140);

        //Show Total
        Label Total = new Label();
        Total.setFont(new Font(30));
        Total.setText("Total");
        Total.setLayoutX(570);
        Total.setLayoutY(140);


        // Create a pane to hold the circle 
        Pane ControllerView = new Pane();
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(AddBall);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(ResetBall);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(AddStrike);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(ResetStrike);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(AddOut);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(ResetOut);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(ScoreUp);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(ScoreDown);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(ShowScoreboard);
        ControllerView.getChildren().add(ResetScoreboard);

        Pane ScoreboardView = new Pane();
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(ShowController);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(ShowBalls);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Strikes);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Outs);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(BallsLabel);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(StrikesLabel);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(OutsLabel);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning1);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning2);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning3);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning4);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning5);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning6);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning7);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning8);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Inning9);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Home);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Away);
        ScoreboardView.getChildren().add(Total);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Controlls = new Scene(ControllerView, 600, 200, Color.GREEN);
        Score = new Scene(ScoreboardView, 700, 320, Color.GREEN);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ScoreBoard"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(Controlls); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
    }

    public void AddBall() {
        Ball.set(Ball.get() + 1);
        if (Ball.get() == 4) {
            Ball.set(0);
            Strike = 0;
        }
        System.out.println(Ball.get());
    }
    public void ResetBall() {
        Ball.set(0);
    }

    public void AddStrike() {
        Strike++;
        if (Strike == 3) {
            Out++;
            Strike = 0;
            Ball.set(0);
        }
    }

    public void ResetStrike() {
        Strike = 0;
    }

    public void AddOut() {
        Out++;
        Strike = 0;
        Ball.set(0);
        if (Out == 3) {
            Inning++;
        }
    }

    public void ResetOut() {
        Out = 0;
    }
    public void ScoreUp() {
        InningScore[Inning]++;
    }
    public void ScoreDown() {
        InningScore[Inning]--;
    }
    public void ResetScoreboard() {
        Ball.set(0);
        Strike = 0;
        Out = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            InningScore[i] = 0;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I just want it to show how many balls there are when I switch back to the Scoreboard scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line from

```
ShowBalls.textProperty().bind(new SimpleIntegerProperty(Ball.get()).asString());
```

to this

```
ShowBalls.textProperty().bind(Ball.asString());
```

As a side note i know your still working on this but since all of your functions are in the same class they all should be private not public and traditionally functions start with a lowercase first letter for example you have

```
public void ResetScoreboard() {
```

when it should be

```
private void resetScoreboard() {
```

same goes for variable names `Ball` should be `ball` I try to reserve capital starting letters for Class names only  I would give java naming conventions a google when you get a chance it helps everyone stay on the same page when reading others code.

Good luck with your project hope it all goes well

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you're a saint!